# Cakephp: multiply jquery binds conflict

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have a page on which i have placed several jquery sliders, some checkboxes and radio buttons.

I post is created on slidestop, change of checkboxes, change or radio buttons. This works great.

On this same page there is a table displayed with this information and in the buttons which are outbound links, i have placed id's which are posted to another controller to track the outbound clicks with their id's.

When the button is clicked a post with the id is done using jquery to this clicks controller.

This works great when the sliders, checkboxes, radio buttons aren't used. As soon as one of those elements are touched the post to this clicks controller on the buttons click doesnt work anymore.

This is what the javascript looks like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".btn").bind("click", function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"),
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "\/clicks"
                });
                return false;
            });
        $("#saveForm").bind("slideStop", function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                async:true, 
                beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#loading").attr("style", " ")
                }, 
                complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    $("#loading").attr("style", "display:none")
                }, 
                data:$("#saveForm").serialize(), 
                dataType:"html", 
                success:function (data, textStatus) {
                    $("#resultaat").html(data);
                }, 
                type:"POST", 
                url:"\/abonnements"
            });
            return false;
        });
        $(".checkbox").bind("change", function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                async:true, 
                beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#loading").attr("style", " ")
                },    
                complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    $("#loading").attr("style", "display:none")
                }, 
                data:$("#saveForm").serialize(), 
                dataType:"html", 
                success:function (data, textStatus) {
                    $("#resultaat").html(data);
                }, 
                type:"POST", 
                url:"\/abonnements"
            });
            return false;
        });
        $(".radio").bind("change", function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                async:true, 
                beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#loading").attr("style", " ")
                }, 
                complete:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    $("#loading").attr("style", "display:none")
                }, 
                data:$("#saveForm").serialize(), 
                dataType:"html", 
                success:function (data, textStatus) {
                    $("#resultaat").html(data);
                }, 
                type:"POST", 
                url:"\/abonnements"
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

I think it's caused by the multiple posts on the same page but i'm not sure. I have been trying to fix this the whole day but couldn't find a solution.

Update:

I found what is causing the other function to fail.

```
    $this->Js->get('#saveForm')->event(
                'slideStop',
                $this->Js->request(
                array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'abonnements'),
                array(
                    'update' => '#resultaat',
                    'data' => $data,
                    'async' => true,    
                    'dataExpression'=>true,
                    'method' => 'POST',
                    'before'   => '$("#loading").attr("style", " ")', 
                    'complete' => '$("#loading").attr("style", "display:none")'
                    ))
                );
```

The action for the .btn which is displayed in the #resultaat table is broken when the update is done by the slideStop action.

This is how the button looks like:

```
<td>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Meer Info',
            $link,
            array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block', 
                    'target' => '_blank', 
                    'id' => $abonnement['Abonnement']['id']
                )
        ); 
    ?> 
</td>
```

The id is needed.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by placing the jquery code for the button click on the element which is updated by the other jquery function. Somehow it lost the bind when the slider updated the element in which another bind is placed.